# Javascript Chain Dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, html

I know that there are a lot of this questions being posted online but I still have difficulty finding what I need.

Currently I have found something that is doing 3 chained dropdown selection maximum. I needed to have 4 and I have tried editing the script but it's not working.

Below is the code that I have edited, is there anything wrong with my code?

```
    <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">


// State lists
var states = new Array();

  states[0] = new Array('Alberta','British Columbia','Ontario');
  states[1] = new Array('Baja California','Chihuahua','Jalisco');
  states[2] = new Array('California','Florida','New York');

  // Province lists
var provinces = new Array();

  provinces[0] = new Array();
  provinces[0][0] = new Array("Province1", "Province2");

// City lists
var cities = new Array();
  cities[0][0] = new Array();
  cities[0][0][0] = new Array('Edmonton','Calgary');
  cities[0][0][1] = new Array('Victoria','Vancouver');


function setStates(){

  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateList = states[cntrySel.selectedIndex];

  changeSelect('state', stateList);
  setProvinces();

}

function setProvinces(){

  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateSel = document.getElementById('state');
  provinceList = provinces[cntrySel.selectedIndex][stateSel.selectedIndex];

  changeSelect('province', provinceList);
  setCities();

}

function setCities(){

  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateSel = document.getElementById('state');
  provinceList = document.getElementById('province');
  cityList = cities[cntrySel.selectedIndex][stateSel.selectedIndex][provinceList.selectedIndex];

  changeSelect('city_town_district', cityList);

}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newList) {

  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;

  for (i=0; i<newList.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newList[i], newList[i], newList[i]);
  }
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="setStates();">
<form name="test">

Country: 
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="setStates();">
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
</select>
<br>

State: 
<select name="state" id="state" onchange="setProvinces();">
  <option value="">Please select a State</option>
</select>
<br>

Province: 
<select name="province" id="province" onchange="setCities();">
  <option value="">Please select a Province</option>
</select>
<br>

City: 
<select name="city_town_district"  id="city_town_district">
  <option value="">Please select a City</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying with `cities` and `provinces` array, why such declaration?

Comment: Hi Arvind, I am trying to show the cities list when the user select something in province dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, one answer and everybody have to do this sometimes.
The year is 2018 and I find a easy way to do this. Easy to add, edit and receive data from server. Bye!
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gillall/8ude23rx)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="slc1" id="slc1" onchange="_1sel();"></select>
    <select name="slc2" id="slc2" onchange="_2sel();"></select>
    <select name="slc3" id="slc3" onchange="_3sel();"></select>
    <select name="slc4" id="slc4"></select>
    <script>
    //just call the method when the select change
        var slc1 = document.getElementById("slc1");
        var slc2 = document.getElementById("slc2");
        var slc3 = document.getElementById("slc3");
        var slc4 = document.getElementById("slc4");

        var dataObj = {//is a valid json
            "brazil": {
                "sp": {
                    "sp1": ["sp1A", "sp1B"],
                    "sp2": ["sp2A"]
                },
                "mg": {
                    "mg1": ["mg1A", "mg1B"],
                    "mg2": ["mg2A", "mg1B"]
                },
                "rj": {
                    "rj1": ["rj1A", "rj1B", "rj1C"],
                    "rj2": ["rj2A", "rj1B"]
                }
            },
            "usa": {
                "ny": {
                    "ny1": ["ny1A","ny1B","ny1C"],
                    "ny2": ["ny2A"]
                },
                "tx": {
                    "tx1": ["tx1A"]
                }
            },
            "uk": {
                "ld": {
                    "ld1": ["ld1A","ld1B","ld1C"],
                    "ld2": ["ld2A"]
                },
                "hm": {
                    "hm1": ["hm1A", "hm1B"]
                }
            }
        }

        let ctrs = Object.keys(dataObj);//countries - Object.keys return an array
        cmo(ctrs, slc1);//push values to select one
        _1sel();//call the first method of chain
        //slc1.value = "usa"
        //slc1.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

        function _1sel() {
            slc2.innerHTML = "";//clear the target select
            let cities = Object.keys(dataObj[slc1.value]);//get the cities from country as array
            cmo(cities, slc2);//push values to select two
            _2sel();//call the second method of chain
        }

        function _2sel() {
            slc3.innerHTML = "";//clear
            let zones = Object.keys(dataObj[slc1.value][slc2.value]);//get the zones from country and city as array
            cmo(zones, slc3);//push values to select three
            _3sel();//call the third method of chain
        }

        function _3sel() {
            slc4.innerHTML = "";//clear
            let staffs = dataObj[slc1.value][slc2.value][slc3.value];//no Obj.keys here, just get the array of values
            cmo(staffs, slc4);//push values to select four
        }

        function cmo(arr, s) {//create options and add to select
            arr.forEach(o => {
                let opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = o;
                opt.innerHTML = o;
                s.add(opt);
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect by any means but it should get you going. Instead of having unrelated arrays I suggest you use some object oriented principles. I've chosen to use JSON to describe the relationships in the data. The other advantage to using JSON is that many server side languages have JSON serializers available to them.

I have kept as much of your code as possible so there is some familiarity for you. However inline event handling is not considered best practice these days. You should look at [Event Listeners/Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead. Or if it was me I would be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) as it irons out much of the cross browser issues you can come across.

```js
/*Use JSON to describe data and its relationship*/

var countries = [{
  "CountryName": "Canada",
  "States": [{
    "StateName": "British Columbia",
    "Provences": [{
      "ProvenceName": "BC P1",
      "Cities": ["Vancouver"]
    }, {
      "ProvenceName": "BC P2",
      "Cities": ["Whistler"]
    }]
  }, {
    "StateName": "Ontario ",
    "Provences": [{
      "ProvenceName": "Ot 1",
      "Cities": ["Ontario"]
    }, {
      "ProvenceName": "Ot 2",
      "Cities": ["Toronto"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "CountryName": "United States",
  "States": [{
    "StateName": "New York",
    "Provences": [{
      "ProvenceName": "NY P1",
      "Cities": ["New York", "New Jersy"]
    }, {
      "ProvenceName": "NY P2",
      "Cities": ["Buffalo"]
    }]
  }, {
    "StateName": "California",
    "Provences": [{
      "ProvenceName": "South",
      "Cities": ["Los Angeles", "San Dieago"]
    }, {
      "ProvenceName": "North",
      "Cities": ["San Francisco"]
    }]
  }]
}];

var selectedCountry;
var selectedState;
var selectedProvence;
var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
var provenceList = document.getElementById("province");
var cityList = document.getElementById("city_town_district");

function setStates(selectedIndex) {

  selectedCountry = countries[selectedIndex];
   stateList.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < selectedCountry.States.length; i++) {
    stateList.options[stateList.length] = new Option(selectedCountry.States[i].StateName, selectedCountry.States[i].StateName, selectedCountry.States[i].StateName);
  }
  
  setProvinces(0);
}

function setProvinces(selectedIndex) {

  selectedState = selectedCountry.States[selectedIndex];
  console.log(selectedState)
  provenceList.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < selectedState.Provences.length; i++) {
    provenceList.options[provenceList.length] = new Option(selectedState.Provences[i].ProvenceName, selectedState.Provences[i].ProvenceName, selectedState.Provences[i].ProvenceName);
  }
  
  setCities(0);
}

function setCities(selectedIndex) {

  selectedProvence = selectedState.Provences[selectedIndex];
  cityList.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < selectedProvence.Cities.length; i++) {
    cityList.options[cityList.length] = new Option(selectedProvence.Cities[i], selectedProvence.Cities[i], selectedProvence.Cities[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
Country:
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="setStates(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
</select>
<br>State:
<select name="state" id="state" onchange="setProvinces(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option value="">Please select a State</option>
</select>
<br>Province:
<select name="province" id="province" onchange="setCities(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option value="">Please select a Province</option>
</select>
<br>City:
<select name="city_town_district" id="city_town_district">
  <option value="">Please select a City</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help! I have tried, somehow it is not working. The country, state, etc data in the javascript is not reflecting on the browser.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Learn how to use `console.log` to track down javascript issues. Are there any javascript errors in the console?